# Core Data - how to initialize entity which has relationship with another entity from CSV file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In Core Data, you can initialize an entity using `insertNewObject: inManagedContext:` method of the `NSEntityDescription` class. However, how can I initialize the entity which has a relationship with another entity?

So in the following two CSV files:

```
1, Mike, CA
2, Robinson, MA
3, Peter, CA
4, Bob, NZ
```

```
1, 2, 20
2, 2, 23
3, 2, 22
4, 1, 32
```

And what I'm trying to connect is the first column of the two file (so one-to-one relationship in this case).

I came up with an idea that you first loop over each line of the first file, and you also loop over each line of the second file, and create new entity only when the first number of those two lines match each other - and skip to the next iteration when it's not. However, this solution either goes computationally heavy or quite convoluted when I try to connect more than two files - for example, if I want to connect six files and each file has 3,000 lines, I have to check the condition 3,000^6 times.

So is it a better way to make an initialization? For some reasons every example I've read so far that uses relationship in its entities already completed those initializations and just directly used SQLite database - so maybe is it impossible to do an initialization from within code and what I should do is first store those CSV data into SQLite database and just copy and paste (or some similar ways) the database to my project?

I also don't know why [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920667/ios-core-data-how-to-properly-initialize-entity-relationships) says I don't have to initialize the relationship part - when I skip the relationship attribute (and insert whatever values to those attributes that don't have a relationship), the insertion doesn't return any errors. However, it's stored `nil` to, so I cannot connect those two entities at all in my code, right?

I use iOS 7 and Xcode 5.

[update]

Suppose both file1 and file2 consist of NSString:

```
for (NSString *row in file1) {
    NSArray *line = [row componentsSepareatedByString:@","];
    File1Entity *file1entity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"File1Entity" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    for (NSString *row2 in file2) {
        NSArray2 *line2 = [row2 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        if (line[0] isEqualToString: line2[0]) {
            File2Entity *file2entity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"File2Entity" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
            file1entity.name = line[1]
            file1entity.residence = line[2]
            file2entity.number = line2[1]
            file2entity.age = line2[2]
            file1entity.n = file2entity
            NSError *err;
            [_managedObjectContext save:&err];
        }
   }
```

The columns of file1 are `n`, `name`, and `residence`, which are `NSNumber`, `NSString`, `NSString`, respectively.

The columns of file2 are `n`, `number`, and `age`, all of which are `NSNumber`.

And I want to connect both `n` as relationship. So do I have to iterate the whole lines here? (Actually, I realized this case doesn't need to iterate the whole part; because this is one-to-one relationship, I can terminate the outer iteration when I detect the matched objects. But it still has to be iterated the whole time whenever I want to use one-to-many or many-to-many relationship, hasn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relationship is effectively just another accessor.  You `set` the relationship between the two entities.  Core Data takes care of the rest.

Imagine you have an entity called Person and another called Address.  These entities have a relationship called `address` from Person to Address and `address` from Address to Person.  You can set the relationship between them via:

```
Person *person = ...;
Address *address = ...;
[person setValue:address forKey:@"address"];
```

That example uses KVC (Key Value Coding). If you have subclasses created and properties defined you could also do:

```
Person *person = ...;
Address *address = ...;
[person setAddress:address];
```

The inverse relationship (Address to Person) is managed automatically by Core Data so you do not need to set the inverse.

As for when you set this relationship, that is entirely up to you and the design of your application.

### Update

Your sample files are not code so no, I cannot use them. Post code and we can discuss that aspect further.

The `...` is where you put code you already know how to do.  Creating the entities.  The sample I posted shows you how to set the *relationship* which is what you asked about.

### Update 2

The line in question should read:

```
file1entity.n = file2entity;
```

You are setting the relationship of `n` on `file1entity` to the instance of `file2entity`.  It is just another property accessor and should be treated the same.

Remember, Core Data is an object graph **first**.  Treat it, and its relationships, as if it is an object graph.

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow what you mean - isn't it what I tried to do using loop, right? I also don't know what you mean in `...`. Could you show me an example using my two sample files (feel free to name columns)?

Comment: Ah, I got I shouldn't connect both `n` property each other - now fixed my original code. Then return to my original question: `is it better way to make an initialization?` Or do I always have to initialize it with those nested loop?

Comment: You could look into storing the objects in dictionaries with the identifier as the key and then look up in the dictionary. That would remove the nested loops.